# Can't explode PHP string using blank space as delimiter

Tags: php, explode

I'm trying to explode a date as a string using blank space as the delimiter.  I've checked that the string is indeed a string.

The string is scraped from a webpage and returns a value like "19 Jul 19" after I've removed the HTML surrounding the value.

I can successfully explode if I copy and paste the value eg 19 Jul 19

Works

```
$str = trim("19 Jul 19");
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

Works

```
$val = "19 Jul 19";
$str = trim($val);
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

Does not work where $str_meeting_date[0] is 19 Jul 19

```
$val = $str_meeting_date[0];
$str = trim($val);
print_r (explode(" ",$str));
```

returns Array ( [0] => 19 Jul 19 )

I've checked that there's no special characters.  The string that is used as the val follows a number of previous explode functions to get the date.

I'm bemused!

Also, my apologies in advance - this is the first question I've asked and if I have over or under explained, I will learn for next time.

Comment: I checked your code, it should work, I can't reproduce: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/3eaf3bdbe34e7ea10a0aaf9d510780ea05ba6184

Comment: At this point it should be obvious that it isn't a standard space then. Hexeditor/bin2hex() instead of just looking at the browser rendition?

Comment: `print_r()` tends to omit and/or obscure useful information. Use `var_dump()` instead. But do also look at the hex representation. I'll bet those spaces aren't `0x20`s.

Answer (score 0):

Definitely  your string has something other than space , you can apply regex on  `preg_split` which is applicable for both whitespaces and tabs

```
$str1="19     Jul 19";
$str2="19 Jul 19";
print_r(preg_split('/\s+/', $str1));
print_r(preg_split('/\s+/', $str2));
```

output

```
Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => Jul [2] => 19 ) Array ( [0] => 19 [1] => Jul [2] => 19 )
```